# How to get output result as zip in HIVE, i am using putty

Tags: hive

> **How to get output result as zip in HIVE.

I am using putty ?**

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

prepend the following runtme setting before you execute your hive query.

```
SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=<codec>
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true
SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true
```

I hope this will help ..!!